# Most Efficient Way to Convert Strings.Builder to Byte Array

Tags: go

I'm using the stringbuilder:

```
var sb strings.Builder
```

I need to convert this to []byte to finally send it with `bytes.NewBuffer()` via http post.  I need this to be as quick as possible.

Currently I do it as follows:

```
var sendText = sb.String()
var byteSend = []byte(sendText)
```

Is this the best way of doing this?

Comment: What about `bytes.NewBufferString(sb.String())`?

Comment: That's a good suggestion.  Will have to do a benchmark to test if it will make a difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `bytes.NewBufferString(sb.String())` if you must start from a `strings.Buffer` and end with `bytes.Buffer`.  This will incur the cost of a `string` to `[]byte` conversion (allocation + copy).

There are better alternatives if the problem statement can be relaxed.

If you have control over the code that writes to the `strings.Builder`, then change the code to write to a `bytes.Buffer` directly.  This is a simple change because `bytes.Buffer` has all of the `strings.Builder` methods.

If your goal is to get an `io.Reader` to use as an HTTP request body, then use `strings.NewReader(sb.String())` to get the `io.Reader`.

These two options do not incur the the cost of the `string` to `[]byte` conversion.